# Create an Account from a new Contact using Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

I am trying to use Process Builder to create an Account using the name of a newly created Contact.

I've managed to get my process to create the new Account, but my challenge is how do I now create the relationship between the Contact and the new Account?

Basically, I want to populate the Account ID into the Account field on the Contact - but I cant seem to work out how to do this?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use a lookup from `Account` to `Contact`, you can set that lookup in your existing process, then add a new process on `Account` that populates its `Id` up to the `Contact`. Make sure they can't evaluate multiple times in the same context.